# How do I deploy the parachute in Assassins Creed Brotherhood for PC?

Tags: pc, assassins-creed-brotherhood

I've finished Leonardo's missions and he's given me a parachute but forgot to include the instructions.
Already read that you need to press X on an Xbox to deploy it but I'm playing on my PC and can't figure it out. I even died once, jumping from the highest tower, hoping it would deploy automagically :-)

Thanks!

Comment: I have the PS3 version which tells you onscreen what key to trigger when you are jumping from high enough to be able to use it. I suppose it should be the same on the PC version. So, get quite high (so you have time to look at the screen before splashing on the floor), jump and hit the right one. Good reflex or good stunt :)

Comment: It's likely to be whatever key you use for your weapon hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is only one consideration for the parachute to deploy. Ezio should be in freefall, not diving or in leap of faith. After you jump of a ledge, press and hold the attack button to deploy the parachute.

Answer (score 5):

Use the attack button.

Also be sure to check your supply of parachutes, as they are limited. You can buy some from the Tailor

Answer (score -1):

Simple: Open your game, then press the Esc button. Select the option "Database" and then select "User Manual". After that you'll see there are lots of options and click on your option - for instance "Parachute". It'll show how you can open the Parachute.